# Get user name inside AJAX success function

Tags: php, ajax

I'm trying to display the username when an AJAX request is successful. 
The problem that I'm running into is that the name remains blank.

Simplified code (removed if statements, checks, and other unrelated code)

```
wp_localize_script('follow-me-ajax', 'ajax_setting', array(
    'ajax_url'              => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
    'ajax_nonce'            => wp_create_nonce('km-ajax-create-nonce'),
    'ajax_follow_success'   => $this->follow_me_success(), 
));
```

AJAX Call

```
var user_to_follow      = $('.km-author-follow a.km-meta-badge').attr('id');

    $.ajax( {
        url : ajax_setting.ajax_url,
        type : 'post', 
        data: {  
            action                      : 'theme_ajax_follow_me',
            security                    : ajax_setting.ajax_nonce,
            'data-follow-user'          : user_to_follow,                       
        },  

        success: function( data ) {
            $('.km-follow-me').html( ajax_setting.ajax_follow_success ).hide().fadeIn( 'slow' );
             console.log( user_to_follow );
        },

    } )
```

Inside the wp ajax function I use this

```
public function theme_addon_ajax_follow_me() {

        ... 

        $target_user    = isset( $_POST['data-follow-user'] ) ? $_POST['data-follow-user'] : false;

        if( ! empty( $_POST['data-follow-user'] ) ) {           
            $this->kiwi_follow_user( $current_user, $target_user );
        }   

        wp_die();   

    }
```

Up next; this function sends the `$target_user ID` to `km_follow_me_author_name`

```
public function kiwi_follow_user( $current_user = 0, $user_to_follow = 0  ) {

        ...     

        $args = array(
            'user_id'   => $current_user,
            'follow_to' => $user_to_follow
        );

        $response_success = $this->km_follow_me_author_name( $args );

    }
```

Function to grab display name based on AJAX's `$_POST['data-follow-user']`

```
public function km_follow_me_author_name( $args = array() ) {

        $author_info    = get_userdata( $args['follow_to'] );

        $author = $author_info->display_name;           

        return $author;

    }
```

The success message and where it goes wrong. `$name` remains blank.

```
public function follow_me_success() {

        $name       = $this->km_follow_me_author_name();

        $content    = sprintf( esc_html__( 'You\'re now following %s.', 'theme' ), $name );

        return $content;

    }
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: when you call `console.log( user_to_follow );` in the `success:` of the AJAX call what does the console log ?

Comment: It shows the correct user id.

Comment: I think I figured it out. I'll first test my code thoroughly and then post a solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

First I removed this line from `wp_localize_script`

```
'ajax_follow_success'   => $this->follow_me_success(),
```

Then changed the success function from AJAX to:

`$('.km-follow-me').html(data).hide().fadeIn( 'slow' );`

Then inside `public function kiwi_follow_user` I used:

```
if ( ! empty( $response ) && $response !== FALSE ) {   
   $this->km_follow_me_success( $user_to_follow );
}
```

And inside the `follow_me_success` function, I replaced `return` with `echo` instead.

```
public function follow_me_success( $target_user = 0 ) {    
    $name       = $this->km_follow_me_author_name( $target_user );    
    $content    = sprintf( esc_html__( 'You\'re now following %s.', 'theme' ), $name );

    echo $content;    
}
```

Minor changes, big difference. :)